# recv() returns -1 (failed with 10054 error)

Tags: c, sockets, winsock

When my client sends a request to the server (both are written in C), `recv()` fails on the client side with error 10054 (`WSAECONNRESET`). My server is a Windows service running on a defined port.

The connection gets established, the sockets are created on both sides, but while sending/receiving, I am facing this issue :/

---> Server Code  <----

```c
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET MainSock, AcceptSock;
int c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
char client_req[1024] = { 0 };
int req_size;
char *end = NULL;

if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsa) != 0)
{
    fprintf(fptr, " WSAStartup Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}

//Create a socket
if ((MainSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    fprintf(fptr, " Could not create socket : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;    //inet_addr("10.10.1.18"); 
server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

//Bind
if (bind(MainSock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    fprintf(fptr, " Bind failed with error code : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

//Listen to incoming connections
if ((listen(MainSock, SOMAXCONN)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    fprintf(fptr, " listen failed with error code : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

//Accept and incoming connection
fprintf(fptr, "\n\n Waiting for incoming connections...");

if ((AcceptSock = accept(MainSock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    fprintf(fptr, "\n Connection accepted on %s", getCurrTime());

    req_size = recv(AcceptSock, client_req, 1024, 0);

    if (req_size > 0)
    {
        //stuff to do
    }                              
}
```

---> Client Code  <----

```c
char *ReturnedData = CreatePacket();
encrypt(ReturnedData);

if ((sent_bytes = send(ServiceSock, ReturnedData, strlen(ReturnedData), 0)) < 0)
{
    err = GetLastError();
    DisplayError = malloc(MINCHAR * sizeof(char));
    sprintf(DisplayError, "Unable to communicate. (%d)", err);
    MessageBox(NULL, DisplayError, "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    free(DisplayError);
    return err;
}

if ((recv_size = recv(ServiceSock, Service_reply, 10000, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)   //Failed here with 10054
{
    err = WSAGetLastError();
    DisplayError = malloc(MINCHAR * sizeof(char));
    sprintf(DisplayError, "Unable to receive information. (%d)", err);
    MessageBox(NULL, DisplayError, " Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    free(DisplayError);
    return err;
}
else
{
    //stuff to do
}
```

Comment: 'CreatePacket()' seems to return a NUL-terminated char array.  Does it?  Where is it freed, (if it does not need freeing, please explain why)?

Comment: Does 'encrypt()' maintain the NUL-termination without introducing any embedded NULs?

Comment: The client does not send that terminating NUL, so how can the server know when a client_req has been completely received?

Comment: The given code has a smell of failing to correctly handle the streaming nature of TCP, where sending a 100 byte message may result in 100 recv() returns, each having loaded one byte into the buffer.

Comment: Same with `send()`.  Both `send()` and `recv()` can return fewer bytes than requested.  You need to handle that on both sides, by running both functions in loops until all expected data is sent/consumed.

Comment: @MartinJames CreatePacket() does not return anything but it stores the output in the global varibale of type char array. It is being freed at the end of the code where I am closing the socket and some garbage collection. 

-> So server is not able to distinguish between 2 different messages as the null-terminator ('\0') is missing at the end of the first message ? Is that so ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau both send() and recv() are working fine when I debug the windows service's exe (which is a server for me). When I install service (using sc.exe) i am getting the 10054 error while receiving.

Comment: @VivekSonawane in TCP, you MUST separate messages explicitly. For each message, you MUST either send the message's length before sending the message's body, or else terminate the message with a unique delimiter. Your code is doing neither. And your use of `send()` and `recv()` IS insufficient, despite whether you THINK they are working. TCP is a byte stream, you MUST treat it as such. That means you CAN'T assume a 1:1 relationship between sends and reads

Comment: @RemyLebeau Agree with you. I do send length of the message and then the actual message. Do you have any good documentation over send() and recv() usage ? Because I have read theory while implementing the same I had no luck.

Comment: @VivekSonawane the code you have shown does not do anything to send/receive a message's length before its data. There are plenty of questions on StackOverflow whose answers show proper use of `send()` and `recv()`

Comment: A global char array?  Does not return anything?  It does, and you send what is returned!

Comment: @MartinJames As of now I am using the way as I have posted the question and that is not my real concern. I do NULL-TERMINATED message before encrypting and send the encrypted one but still it has no effect.

Comment: A common cause of unexpected abortive disconnect (leading to `WSAECONNRESET`) is one side of the connection closing a socket with unread data still queued.